# getting string value from jscript to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

I've a little doubt with this...how can i set/retrieve the value from a jsp page jscript string named "z" in a servlet.I need to use it in servlet...I'M exploring new thing n its a new thing for me as i"m new to these thing...Thanks for the quick help....i need the value of password if pass1 and pass2 are same,n then i need to retrieve it in servlet if pass1==pass2...tell me a way...for that i wrote a jscript to check pass1==pass2..

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>New User Registration</title>
    <script>
    function myFunction(){
        var x = document.forms["newForm"]["pass1"].value;
        var y = document.forms["newForm"]["pass2"].value;
    if(x==y){
        document.newForm.submit();var z=x;
        return true;
        }
        else {
        alert("Passwords not matching!!!");}
        }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <fieldset>
    <form name=newForm action="RegServlet">Username:<input
        type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password:<input type="text" name="pass1" id="pass1"><br>
    Confirm Password:<input type="text" name="pass2" id="pass2"><br>
    <input type="submit" onclick=myFunction() value="Create"></input></form>
    </fieldset>

    </body>
    </html>
```

servlet

```
package myPack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RegServlet
 */
public class RegServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public RegServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s1=request.getParameter("username");
        System.out.println(s1);

        String s2=request.getParameter("");//HERE I NEED THE PAssword value if PASS!==PASS2
        System.out.println(s2);

        String c="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";

        Connection con=null;
        System.out.println("Connection OK");
        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            System.out.println("Done2");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(c, "root", "MyNewPass");
            System.out.println("Done3");

            PreparedStatement ps=null;
            System.out.println("Done4");

            String qs = "insert into userinfo values(?,?);";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(qs);
            ps.setString(1,s1);
            ps.setString(2,s2);
            System.out.println("Success");
            ps.execute();
            con.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed: " + e.toString());
        // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Failed");}}


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a hidden field in your form; then in your "onsubmit" event set the value of that field to z.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="zValue" id="zValue">
```

in `onsubmit` event

```
document.getElementById("zValue").value="The value I want to send";
```

and retrieve in your servlet as any other parameter.

Comment: Bro i already set the value of z in the above jsp as var z=x;......what i need is to retrieve the value of z in a servlet....

Comment: The servlet will only receive the data from the `input`/`select`/`textArea` fields in the form that you submit. All of the JS variables will be ignored.

Comment: Hm!! Thnx Bro i need the value of password if pass1 and pass2 are same,n then i need to retrieve it in servlet if pass1==pass2...tell me a way...for that i wrote a jscript to check pass1==pass2

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example i use in tomcat. It will get you all parameters that are send in a POST or GET request. Be advised that this does not cover multicast requests (which are needed for file transfers).
 I don't know if it will work for you, as you have not specified you servlet container.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;


@WebServlet(description = "A simple request test.", urlPatterns = { "/requesttest" })

public class RequestTest extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String title = "Reading All Request Parameters";
    out.println("<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FDF5E6\">\n" +
                "<H1 ALIGN=CENTER>" + title + "</H1>\n" +
                "<TABLE BORDER=1 ALIGN=CENTER>\n" +
                "<TR BGCOLOR=\"#FFAD00\">\n" +
                "<TH>Parameter Name<TH>Parameter Value(s)");
    Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
    while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
      out.println("<TR><TD>" + paramName + "\n<TD>");
      String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
      if (paramValues.length == 1) {
        String paramValue = paramValues[0];
        if (paramValue.length() == 0)
          out.print("<I>No Value</I>");
        else
          out.print(paramValue);
      } else {
        out.println("<UL>");
        for(int i=0; i<paramValues.length; i++) {
          out.println("<LI>" + paramValues[i]);
        }
        out.println("</UL>");
      }
    }
    out.println("</TABLE>\n</BODY></HTML>");

  }

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Seeing as you edited your question with your servlet code, the answer should be really simple.

```
 String s2=request.getParameter("pass1");
```

This should get you the value that is transmitted within the password field. This is no different than you getting the username with `String s1=request.getParameter("username");`

Comment: i've posted the servlet...thnx for the help ;-)